# Complex jQuery filter() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter

I am trying to dynamically insert links to return to the top of the document at the end of every section of a web page (sad to say, but it's table-based layout).  I'm using the jQuery `filter()` selector, and while I get no error, it's not making any changes in the browser output.  When I use `alert()` with the variable, it says `Object object`.  I understand that the problem is in the line where I define the filter itself, but I was unable to find a similar example, and I don't know how to fix it.

Here's the code:

**HTML**

```
<table>
  <tr class="head"><td colspan="2">section title 1 </td></tr>
  <tr><td>text</td>
    <td><img /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr><td>text</td>
    <td>< img /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="head"><td colspan="2">section title 2 </td></tr>
  <tr><td>text</td>
    <td><img /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr><td>text</td>
    <td>< img /></td>
  </tr>
<!-- you get the point -->
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var lastRow = $('tr').filter(function(){
        return $(this).next()==$(".head"); // Here's the problem, IMO
    });
    var a = '<tr class="toTop"><td class="top" style="text-align:right" colspan="2"><a href="#main">go to top &uarr;</a></td></tr>';
    lastRow.after(a);
});
```

The script attempts to select each row that precedes a row with `class="head"` and insert a row with a `top` link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you are comparing 2 different objects that is always `false`, you should use `is` method or `length` property:

```
var lastRow = $('tr').filter(function(){
    return $(this).next(".head").length;         
    // return $(this).next().is(".head"); 
});
```

However, I'd suggest using `.prev()` method:

```
$('tr.head').prev(); // selects the previous sibling tr element
```

Comment: Okay, I'll call you ;).

Comment: You got lucky, for some reason the guy who posted an answer before you, which was less thorough but also correct, deleted his post! If he hadn't, I would've had a difficult decision, between marking your more complete answer, or his more prompt one.